# android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE outgoing call not answered and outgoing call rejected?

Tags: android

I'm developing a call logs app. using below code, callType possible values I know are:
1 = incoming call answered, 2 = outgoing call, 3 = incoming call not answered, 5 = incoming call rejected. 
what are values for outgoing call not answered" and "outgoing call rejected"

```
String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
Cursor cur = cr.query(callUri, null, null, null, strOrder);
// loop through cursor
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
     String callType = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never use an int to check for a type (eg. `if (callType == 1)`) as that 1 may mean something else in different Android versions. Instead, use the `constants` given by the API. In your case, these are

- `CallsLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE` for incoming calls
- `CallsLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE` for missed calls
- `CallsLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE` for outgoing calls
- `CallsLog.Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE` for voicemail calls

You should never bother which constant has what value (1, 2 or 3), as those may change, but their names (`INCOMING_TYPE`, `MISSED_TYPE`, `OUTGOING_TYPE`, `VOICEMAIL_TYPE`) definitely won't change.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes I should use constants thanks for advice. but what are constants for outgoing rejected or not answered?

Comment: You probably don't know them because there aren't any constants for those, the ones I listed are the only ones in the `Calls` class, You can check it out yourself [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html), but only  the ones I put are listed as call types.

Comment: It sounds calls class does not have complete constants because for example I found value 5 is "incoming call rejected" but there is no constant for that!

Comment: If the class doesn't have them, then they don't exist. Android itself uses those constants, so if they don't exist there is no way you will receive other call types. If you want, you can try logging all call types and see what values you get for each.